# Rails 3 form_for ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, action, form-for

I have method in my controller:

```
def work_here
 @company = Company.find(params[:id])
 current_user.work_apply(current_user, @company)
 redirect_to company_path
end
```

On my view:

```
<%= render 'companies/work_form' if signed_in? %>
```

_work_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for company, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "companies", :action => "work_here" } do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => company.id %>
<%= f.submit "I working here" %>
```

<% end %>

And I have a work_here.js.erb file:

```
$("#work_at_form").html("<%= escape_javascript("render('companies/works')") %>")
```

But my form works without ajax request(in other pages ajax forks fine), my js.erb file never use.
Can anyone give me advise?
Thanks.

Comment: Are all javascript files included in that specific page? Also check that html generated has the correct attributes on the <form> tag

Comment: Yes, everything is ok at this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The work_here.js.erb can't be read because you never call it. A redirect is allways do. render it when the request is js format.

```
def work_here
 @company = Company.find(params[:id])
 current_user.work_apply(current_user, @company)
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to company_path }
   format.js { render }
 end
end
```