# Create new object without redirecting to new_xxx_path in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed [Rails 3 form_for ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791118/rails-3-form-for-ajax-call) post to create new event_criteria_option object in rails, without redirecting to new_event_criteria_option_path. I want to put directly the form in a page without redirecting to a new path.I want to put it in events/show view and my relation is Event has_many :event_criterias, Event_criterias has_many :event_criteria options.

EDIT 2:

This is my controller:

```
def create
@event_criteria_option = EventCriteriaOption.new(params[:event_criteria_option])

respond_to do |format|
  if @event_criteria_option.save
    flash[:notice] = "Event criteria option successfully created"
    format.html { redirect_to(event_criteria_path(EventCriteria.find(@event_criteria_option.event_criteria_id)), :notice => 'Event criteria option was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @event_criteria_option, :status => :created, :location => @event_criteria_option }
    format.js { redirect_to event_path(Event.find(session[:event_id])) }
    #render :js => @event_criteria_option, :status => :created, :location => @event_criteria_option, :layout => !request.xhr?
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @event_criteria_option.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js { render :js => @event_criteria_option.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end

end
```

end

This is my view:

```
<% if !event_criteria.is_free && !event_criteria.is_exclusive %>
        <td>Show options <%= check_box_tag "show_event_criteria_options"+cont.to_s, "event_criteria_options"+cont.to_s, false, :class => "check_buttons" %></td>
    <% end %>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="event_criteria_options<%=cont.to_s%>", style="display: none;" >    
        <% session[:event_id] = @event.id  %>
        <%= form_for (:event_criteria_option, :remote => true, :url => {:id => 'event_criteria_option_form', :controller => "event_criteria_options", :action => "create", :format => :js}) do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :event_criteria_id, :value => event_criteria.id %>
          <%= f.label :value, "Event criteria option value"%>
          <%= f.text_field :value %>
          <%= f.submit "Add option value", :disable_with => 'Adding option value...'%>
        <% end %>
```

With this code remote form works and creates an event_criteria_option. Also I created create.js.erb empty file, your code changing your @value for @event_criteria_option gives me an error. But the problem is that I show remote form with jQuery when I push a the check_box. And when it redirect back to the event/xx path, the remote form with event_criteria_options is hidden, it is necessary to push check box again to show them. Do you understand? jeje How can I solve it? thanks

Comment: I think you need use `fields_for` helper to do that.

Comment: What Rails version do you use? if Rails 3 or greater then look for :remote => true in the link_to, if Rails 2 then link_to_remote will be the solution for the AJAX in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

See this post for the demonstrate of usage of Ajax to call a controller method, so you don't have to make a redirect to a new path.

[Rails 3 form_for ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791118/rails-3-form-for-ajax-call)

Hope this help you.

EDIT 1: Use `form_tag` instead.

```
<%= form_tag('/event_criteria_options/new', :remote => true, :format => :js) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :event_criteria_id, :value => event_criteria.id %>
  <%= label_tag :value, "Event criteria option value"%>
  <%= text_field_tag :value%>
  <%= submit_tag "Add option value", :disable_with => 'Adding option value...'%>
<% end %>
```

note that at the form criation moment you should be able to retrieve the `EventCriteria.id` to generate the form correctly.

**EDIT 2**

Try to modify your action to the following:

```
def new
 @event_criteria_id = params[:event_criteria_id]
 @value = params[:value]
 @event_criteria_option = EventCriteriaOption.create!(:event_criteria_id => @event_criteria_id, :value => @value)


respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @event_criteria_option }
  format.js { render } # Guess that is something missing here..
end
```

Check this URL and see if it can help you in any way.
http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

**EDIT 3**

Since your object is being created just create a new file with the action name, in this case `create.js.erb` in the `views` related directory with the following content:

### create.js.erb

```
$('body').html("<p>New Event Criteria Option created successful! </p>").append("<br /><b><%= escape_javaScript(@value) %></b>");
```

The above line will insert a new paragraph inside your document body with that content. But you can handly the output as you want to. That's only javascript/jQuery.

Another point, if you are dealing with Rails 3, it's a good practice to start using `respond_with`

your new `create` action should looks like:

```
def new
 @event_criteria_id = params[:event_criteria_id]
 @value = params[:value]
 @event_criteria_option = EventCriteriaOption.create!(:event_criteria_id =>    @event_criteria_id, :value => @value)
 respond_with(@value)
end
```

And at the top of your controller put this:

```
class EventCriteriaController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
  .
  .
  end
end
```

**EDIT 4**

Use a session and create a flag to store if is checked or not.

```
class EventCriteriaController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    session[:checked] = true
  .
  .
  end
end
```

And then in your view, check for this `session[:checked]`

view:

```
<% if session[:checked] %>
.
.
# code to make your checkbox with check value
<% else %>
# code to make your checkbox unchecked 
.
<% end %>
```

Comment: How your model relantionship looks like? you may want to take a look in some screencasts about your situation.

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested+forms

Comment: Event has_many :event_criterias, Event_criterias has_many :event_criteria options

Comment: But I don't want nested form, I want to create new event_criteria_option for event_criteria, I don't want to make a form for existing event_criteria_options

Comment: @Tomas I have edited my answer above. Check to see whether this works for you.

Comment: @Tomas I've changed the syntax. Take a look.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I write something in the text_field_tag and I click on button to submit, it doesn't  save the new event_criteria_option.

Comment: So, what's heppening? can you see any error message on the logs? could you paste it here?

Comment: I added this parameter url{ :cotroller => "event_criteria_options", :action => "new", method => "get"} but it gives me a route error that ir can't find event_criteria_options/new, because it is doing a POST when submit the form. But I put methos => "get" I don't know why it is doing a post?

Comment: because it is a POST in fact, not a GET, try to change `method => "get"` to `method => "post"` and see if it works.

Comment: The problem is that it isn't working with AJAX,when I click the button it goes to event_criteria_options/new path and tells me "Couldn't find EventCriteria with ID=0". I don't want to redirect I want to create new object remotetly but I am doing something wrong.

Comment: are you looking to the source code generated to see if it is passing the value correctly to that hidden_field? I edited my response below, see the edit2 part.

Comment: Hi Kleber first of all thanks for your help. I edited my question and I put all my code of view, controller and generated html. And the problem is when I click the button it redirects me to event_criteria_option/new view. And I dont want it I want to call remotely. What happen?

Comment: I get to save the event_criteria_option with create action, but it redirects me to event_criteria_options/create.js.erb. How can I stay in the same path without redirecting anywhere?

Comment: @Tomas oh good to know you did this works, I've edited my answer with a new EDIT3 comments. Take a look and shot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I try it before and the problem is when the page is displayed this div is hidden because I use `<div id="event_criteria_options<%=cont.to_s%>", style="display: none;" >`

Comment: @Tomas change the `checkbox` properties on the `create.js.erb` file.

Comment: How? if I am redirecting to `format.js { redirect_to event_path(Event.find(session[:event_id])) }` in the controller. What I have to put in the create.js.erb?

Comment: In your `create.js.erb` you may have to change the attributes for this specific checkbox with `$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', true);`

Comment: Hi Kleber, thanks but it doesn't work, I think it happen because I am redirecting in the controller `format.js { redirect_to event_path(Event.find(session[:event_id])) }` and it no executes the code tha is in create.js.erb

Comment: As I told you, you shouldnt have a `redirect_to` inside the brackets thro. Leave just `format.js` that it will render the `create.js.erb` file instead.

Comment: Yes but if I don't use redirect_to, if I use respond_to it doesn't redirects me to correct path. It goes to `http://localhost:3000/event_criteria_options.js?id=event_criteria_option_form` ans stops there. And I want to stay in event/xx path.